# Unity 5.6.7 - UnityWebRequest SSL/HTTPS

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, https, unitywebrequest

While using **Unity 5.6.7**, I'm having issues accessing a secured server through HTTPS on Android.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

This is not an issue when using recent versions of Unity as *UnityWebRequest* has the *CertificateHandler* attribute where I can validate the connection, unfortunately in 5.6.7 this does not exist and I would like to avoid updating the engine.

Please help!
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use a different Http Client?  There is the regular HttpWebRequest which is built-in to .NET, although I'm not sure what the difference is.

I believe there is also the newer HttpClient libraray, and then there is the tried and true RestSharp open source lib.  These may help unless there is a really low level issue with the way Unity does requests that would affect all of these libs.